# Understand CSS text position

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I want to vertically align text relative to a div positions next to it, like the follow:
[image]

But while try to do it I've notice that the height of the wrapper div that wraps the text and the cube, is a bit higher than it should, as you can see here:
https://jsfiddle.net/x7sr9mb1/1/

```css
.table-keys-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
}

.key-color {
  display: inline-block;
  background: black;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-key">
  <div class="table-keys-wrapper">
    <span id="key-sow" class="key-color"></span>
    <span class="key-text">Sowing</span>
  </div>
  <div class="table-keys-wrapper">
    <span id="key-plant" class="key-color"></span>
    <span class="key-text">Planting</span>
  </div>
  <div class="table-keys-wrapper">
    <span id="key-harvest" class="key-color"></span>
    <span class="key-text">Harvesting</span>
  </div>
  <div class="table-keys-wrapper">
    <span id="key-storage" class="key-color"></span>
    <span class="key-text">Storage</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The results:

[image]

Why the outer div doesn't get the cube's height, as it's height is set to `height: auto;` (default)

Another question, what is the best way to vertical align the text relatively to the cubes?

Much appreciate the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inline-block`s elements , just like text, stands on the `baseline`.

`baseline` is the default value to `vertical-align`.

reset this value to `vertical-align:middle` for your `inline-block` boxes

```
.key-color{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;/* reset */
  background: black;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because the `.key-text` span has `vertical-align:baseline` by default.

If you will add `vertical-align:middle` to the children it will take the full height of the parent.

```css
.table-keys-wrapper{
  display: inline-block;
}

.table-keys-wrapper * {
  vertical-align:middle;  
}
.key-color{
  display: inline-block;
  background: black;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-key">
  <div class="table-keys-wrapper">
    <span id="key-sow" class="key-color"></span>
    <span class="key-text">Sowing</span>
  </div>
  <div class="table-keys-wrapper">
    <span id="key-plant" class="key-color"></span>
    <span class="key-text">Planting</span>
  </div>
  <div class="table-keys-wrapper">
    <span id="key-harvest" class="key-color"></span>
    <span class="key-text">Harvesting</span>
  </div>
  <div class="table-keys-wrapper">
    <span id="key-storage" class="key-color"></span>
    <span class="key-text">Storage</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try position: absolute;

```css
.table-keys-wrapper{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.key-color{
  display: inline-block;
  background: black;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
}

.key-text{
  padding-left: 22px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-key">
  <div class="table-keys-wrapper">
    <span id="key-sow" class="key-color"></span>
    <span class="key-text">Sowing</span>
  </div>
  <div class="table-keys-wrapper">
    <span id="key-plant" class="key-color"></span>
    <span class="key-text">Planting</span>
  </div>
  <div class="table-keys-wrapper">
    <span id="key-harvest" class="key-color"></span>
    <span class="key-text">Harvesting</span>
  </div>
  <div class="table-keys-wrapper">
    <span id="key-storage" class="key-color"></span>
    <span class="key-text">Storage</span>
  </div>
 </div>
```